# Retain Data from 27 bit to 19 bit conversion

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have an access control solution where the 27 bit format is 13 bits for the facility code and 14 bits for the badge ID. Conversely, I need to convert it into 8 bits for the facility code and 16 bits for the badge ID.

What is the largest number I can convert from on the 27 bit side to get the same result using the 8 bit facility code size? Meaning, if I have 13 bits for the facility code, how many bits can I chop off to still get the same result and an 8 bit size?

Comment: I really don't understand the question. Can you give an example? It looks like you're asking "how many bits do I lose going from 13 bits to 8 bits" (= 5) or "what's the largest number I can store in 8 bits" (255 in plain binary, but if you're using BCD or something else then all bets are off).

Comment: yes, plain binary. I'd like to know how many MSB I can chop off to still retain the same number and not lose data (i.e. if it's 5 MSB and gets me 255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the facility code is never greater than 255, you can chop off the 5 most significant bits (i.e. keep the 8 least significant ones), without losing information.